# How do I prune images with verbose output with Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I am looking for a way to print extra information and activity during Docker prune operation. I can't find any real info on the new. Is there a way to print verbose information about the pruning during the operation. It looks like  a black box operation now with no activity until it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, prune operation doesn't provide detailed information during the process, and you usually only see a summary of what has been removed after the operation completes.

You can do manual inspection before pruning. Before running the prune command, you can manually list the objects that would be affected. For example, `docker images -f dangling=true` will show you the dangling (unused) images that would be removed by a docker image prune.

In addition, you can monitor Docker events in real-time. Running `docker events` in a separate terminal window before starting the prune operation can give you some insights into what Docker is doing in real-time, although this might not provide all the details you're looking for.